# How hide databases that I am not authorised to use in SQL Server Management Studio 2016 from a non serevr administrator?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have do have a shared host contract environment. In this server there are a lot of databases being hosted for each customer resulting in thousands of databases being listed every time.

I would like to be able to configure Management Studio to hide all databases except the one which I'm authorized to use.

**Important. I'm not server owner. I cannot REVOKE the VIEW ANY DATABASE.**

Comment: There are no way to hide it without modifying VIEW ANY DATABASE permission. It is by design.This is one of the most wanted features since 2005, but MS ignores it.

Comment: However, according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt588477.aspx , 16.3 version (Aug 2016) should allow to filter the databases

Comment: Just downloaded and installed 16.3 version, I'm confirming the filter is working - go to Databases node and click Filter button.